# Alphabet II: Unified Alloy Bonds

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, language

As always, good luck!

> Caution your tongue, the king you will abide.
>
> Scribe! Yes sire?
>
> The
>
> new table will arrive soon! Seat it left of seaside.

---

### Hints

The `wordplay` tag is used here to show that the use of the words is the primary focus, but to reach a correct answer, you'll need the `language` tag.

> A viridescent color of glaucous shade.

Comment: It's been some time now, can we get more hints?